# Has anyone successfully used mach_inject for Finder in Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, finder

Just wondering if anyone has done this successfully and what were the steps of making it work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

GrowlSafari uses mach_inject.. it works.. I tried reverse engineering but I don't understand why it aint working for my bundle loader (wich is based on growlsafari) there's not really anything in it that would say it is working on snow.. but you could always try iam still a froob

Answer (score 0):

I know that SIMBL use mach_inject ( like dropbox and google drive )
and that the SIMBL Plugin and Open Source ColorfulSidebar inject itself in the Finder

[here](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/25/get-color-sidebar-icons-back-in-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-finder-windows/) for the plugin source

Hope that help!

Answer (score 0):

`mach_inject` is used to inject code into arbitrary Mac OS X process, however `mach_override` overrides code within the same process. You can see an example of using both in my [FinderMenu](https://github.com/infinitelabs/FinderMenu) project, which adds items to Finder context menu. In this project, I use `mach_inject` to load my custom bundle into Finder process, and after that `mach_override` to replace context menu class method implementation.